# Why would my cmder show Scrambled Code when 'sudo su'

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I'm using cmder to access linux.
When I'm switching to `sudo su`, the words will be scrambled like this:
[image]
[image]

Any idea why this happens? How can I fix this?
BTW, I'm using windows 10 and bash shell.

Comment: Different values for the `$TERM` environment variable? Different `locale`? Which supported Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I checked the `$TERM` = xterm-256color, `LANG`=en_US.UTF-8, linux version = CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)